# Question on SOAP API Task record create ActivityDate field .NET

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, tasks

I prepared a list of tasks with subject,activitydate,description,whatid,whoid filled.

Then I did a create operation using SOAP API. The records were created into system but the none of the record's Activitydate field has value.

I don't know what I missed here. Please help!

[image]

[image]

The above code builds the Task object.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are assigning the date values to the ActivityDate? They should be set in ISO8601 format. The timestamp on an [ActivityDate](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) should be set to midnight UTC.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Here's the modified code, still have problem after I added ".ToUniversalTime()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its in C#, in which case you need to also set the additional specified flag for each property that's not a string, e.g. add

```
ActivityDateSpecified = true;
```